# Can I delete manually data files for entire database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I like to optimize my backup strategy of my MongoDB. I have dedicated folders for each database:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /mongodb
  directoryPerDB: true
  journal:
    enabled: true
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      directoryForIndexes: true
```

Gives folders like this:

```
$ tree -d /mongodb
/mongodb
├── admin
│   ├── collection
│   └── index
├── config
│   ├── collection
│   └── index
├── finaldata
│   ├── collection
│   └── index
├── diagnostic.data
├── temporarydata
│   ├── collection
│   └── index
├── journal
├── local
│   ├── collection
│   └── index
└── _tmp
```

Folder/database `temporarydata` contains only temporary data, as the name implies. I like to exclude folder `/mongodb/temporarydata` from my backup. What happens if this folder is missing from restore, i.e. what happens if this folder is deleted.

Of course, after restore I have to create a fresh and empty `temporarydata` database with all collections and indexes.

The Mongo Deployment is a Sharded Cluster. Database `temporarydata` is sharded but all collections in this database are not sharded (I like to distribute the data by using a different Primary Shard, that's the reason why this database has sharding enabled)

Note, I don't like to delete single *.wt files as mentioned in https://serverfault.com/q/911606/463025, the entire database folder would be deleted.

Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I deployed a sharded Cluster on my PC and run a test.

- Stopping all `mongod` and `mongos` services
- Delete all `dbPath` at PRIMARY hosts
- Delete all `dbPath` at ARBITER hosts
- Delete folder `temporarydata` at SECONDARY hosts

Then I would have the situation like I have after a restore from filesystem restore.

- Start SECONDARY host in [standalone maintenance mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/)
- Drop temporary database: `db.getSiblingDB("temporarydata").dropDatabase()`
- Shutdown the MongoDB
- Repeat above with all shards
- Start all `mongod` and `mongos` services in your cluster

The cluster started successfully without any error - at least I did not see any. So in principle it seems to work.

**However**, for testing I deleted also folder+database `finaldata`. This database is sharded and has sharded collections. After deleting the `finaldata` folder I was not able anymore to start the SECONDARY mongod service - not even in "standalone maintenance mode". Option `--repair` does not help either.

Unless I will get a qualified answer on my question I will not go for this backup strategy, it is to risky.